# AWS SES SendBulkTemplatedEmail, example and what happens if quota is exceeded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have two questions regarding AWS SES SendBulkTemplatedEmail:

1) Does anyone know about any step-by-step tutorial in .Net? I have only seen examples using the CLI, and I am fumbling with the API to try to make it work.

2) Each SendBulkTemplatedEmail request can contain 50 destinations (recipients). My daily send quota is 100,000 emails, and my rate is 14 per second. Does that mean I must send in 14 destinations max per call, and then sleep the thread for a second before sending in the next call with 14 recipients? Or can I send in the full 50 per call? If I do 50, do I still have to sleep the thread? Or will AWS manage this and queue the messages?

Answer (score 4):

I've been working with AWS SES recently. I'm pretty sure you can send 50 destinations in a single call to SES even though your max send rate is 14ps. I was able to.

Definition of Max Send Rate: The maximum number of emails that Amazon SES can accept from your account per second. You can exceed this limit for short bursts, but not for a sustained period of time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console

Hope this helps.