# Node.js(LoopBack 3) - How many recipients can I send emails to by AWS SES?

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-ses, loopback

As so far, I've been sending emails to multiple recipients by **Sakura Japan** SMTP server in my `LoopBack` app.

```
{
  "emailDs": {
    "name": "emailDs",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [{
      "type": "smtp",
      "host": "myapp.sakura.ne.jp",
      "secure": false,
      "port": 587,
      "tls": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      },
      "auth": {
        "user": "~ ~ ~.sakura.ne.jp",
        "pass": "~ ~ ~"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

> It's almost working properly unless the number of recipients is much less than **100**. *But it won't work when the number quite over* **100** - e.g. **150**.

---

**Thus**, I'm going to migrate `AWS SES` but I wonder if there would be any **restriction** with the number of recipients just due to the [following quotation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html):

> The message cannot include more than 50 recipients, across the To:, CC: and BCC: fields. If you need to send an email message to a larger audience, you can divide your recipient list into groups of 50 or fewer, and then call the sendEmail method several times to send the message to each group.

**So, please anybody tells me whether there's a limit with the number of recipients or not if you've experienced in.**

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here the sample code of `AWS SES` goes:

```js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create sendBulkTemplatedEmail params 
var params = {
  Destinations: [ /* required */
    {
      Destination: { /* required */
        CcAddresses: [
          'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
          /* more items */
        ],
        ToAddresses: [
          'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
          'EMAIL_ADDRESS'
          /* more items */
        ]
      },
      ReplacementTemplateData: '{ \"REPLACEMENT_TAG_NAME\":\"REPLACEMENT_VALUE\" }'
  },
  ],
  Source: 'EMAIL_ADDRESS', /* required */
  Template: 'TEMPLATE_NAME', /* required */
  DefaultTemplateData: '{ \"REPLACEMENT_TAG_NAME\":\"REPLACEMENT_VALUE\" }',
  ReplyToAddresses: [
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS'
  ]
};


// Create the promise and SES service object
var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendBulkTemplatedEmail(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
sendPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  });
```

Comment: What is your question, You can't have more then 50 recipient in a single SMTP conversation or a single Sendmail/Sendrawemail API call. If you add more then 50 recipients, SES will reject the email.  Based on your email per second limit set by AWS, you can choose the recipient and make multiple api calls.

Comment: @James Dean - Thanks for your attention. `If you add more then 50 recipients, SES will reject the email` - would you prove your statement for me with some proofs?

Comment: Try adding more then 50 recipient address in a single api or single sendBulkTemplatedEmail() api call, you'll get rejection error.  Your question and your answer given below doesn't match anywhere.

Comment: @James Dean - Thanks for your understanding support. I'm now sure that your advice is quite reasonable. I'll update my answer asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `AWS SES` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html), I've thought that I could send **bulk mails without any limitation** by using `sendBulkTemplatedEmail()` function of AWS **JS SDK**.

> Create an object to pass the parameter values that define the email to be sent, including sender and receiver addresses, subject, email body in plain text and HTML formats, to the sendBulkTemplatedEmail method of the AWS.SES client class. To call the sendBulkTemplatedEmail method, create a promise for invoking an Amazon SES service object, passing the parameters. Then handle the response in the promise callback.

---

However, the following 2 links explain me the different workaround for the production lifecycle since there's an **even technical restriction of 50 recipients**.

[AWS SES SendBulkTemplatedEmail, example and what happens if quota is exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718532/aws-ses-sendbulktemplatedemail-example-and-what-happens-if-quota-is-exceeded)

[Managing Your Amazon SES Sending Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html)

So, `AWS SES` recommends that I'd call `sendEmail()` once for every recipient.

> Sending limits are based on recipients rather than on messages. For example, an email that has 10 recipients counts as 10 against your quota. However, we do not recommend that you send an email to multiple recipients in one call to SendEmail because if the call to Amazon SES fails (for example, the request is improperly formatted), the entire email will be rejected and none of the recipients will get the intended email. We recommend that you call SendEmail once for every recipient.

---

**To make a long story short**,

- There's no theoretical restriction of recipient number when we send mails to multiple addresses.
- But there's a technical restriction of 50 recipients when we send bulk mails by calling `sendBulkTemplatedEmail()`
- The best solution is to send an email to every recipient by calling 'sendEmail()' multiple times.

Thanks for attention.